# AngularJS ui-grid hide all the rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) i just want header to be visible and all the rows will be hidden. Can someone guide how to make this change ?

For the same i have created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nujpd76y/)

currently the `css` is below, i dont know how to change `css` for this problem :-

```
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna hide all rows (ONLY USING CSS) just do the following

```
.ui-grid-viewport{
  display:none;
}
.ui-grid{
  height:100% !important;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nujpd76y/5/

Well, this will permanently hide your rows, if that is what you want. Otherwise if you could just explain your use-case / requirement  ... as in what you are trying to do so as we can suggest a more "angular way" to do this. :)

> UPDATE:

If you want to hide header text then add following

```
.ui-grid-header-cell-label{
  display: none;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nujpd76y/7/

Hope this helps!

Comment: but it is still showing area for rows.. i only want to show header nothing else. doesn't matter with CSS or without CSS. only header need to visible. As i have custom table to show the data and i am using this header as for data input and sort.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for the answer. What if i dont want header text to be visible ?